# Customizing Home Page with Pagelines Platform

Tags: search, homepage

I am finding someone who is familiar with Pagelines and could give me a little help in locating the file to edit.

I am running my Word Press blog with Pagelines Platform Free Version and have encountered some difficulties in customizing my home page and the search results page.

By default, Platform shows 30 most recent posts in the first page of the home page and 30 search results as well in the first page of search results.

However, the page is too long and I would like to cut the page to only showing 10 results / posts per page.

There isn't a home.php for me to edit and I have found postloop.php but no luck.

Does anyone knows how to customize the home page and search results page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is simple is Word Press, regardless of the theme you are using.

Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most

This would be better than editing your (child) theme.

I am sorry that I went on too much in code editing and forgot the most basic and easy things.

But if anyone could advice how to edit the home page (e.g. adding in a new slideshow area) of the Pagelines Platform theme, I am more than happy to hear that.